# Como puedo hacer para que una funcion se ejecute cuando otra haya terminado?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async

Tengo 11 funciones que deben ejecutarse en mi programa. Estas estan en el main de la aplicacion.

Mi problema es que cada una de las funciones dependen entre si. Quiere decir que necesito que la funcion 2 se ejecute solamente si la funcion 1 se termino completamente.

Estube leyendo sobre async task y wait, pero cada vez que las implemento. No todas las funciones esperan o algunas se caen.

Cada funcion que tengo es de tipo void. Como puedo hacer esto?

Muchas gracias

Aqui esta parte de mi codigo el cual include 2 funciones.

La funcion getUsers se repite constantemente y genera una y otra vez el mismo archivo sin parar.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        getTickets().Wait();
        getUsers().Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AddLog(string.Format(ex.ToString()));
    }
}


public static async Task getTickets()
{
    string firstTicketURL = "http://localhost/testapi/testTickets.json";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    var textWriter = File.CreateText(@"test.csv");
    var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter);
    csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
    var counter = 0;

    try
    {
        while (firstTicketURL != "")
        {
            counter++;
            var client = new RestClient(firstTicketURL);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var content = response.Content;

            string resultJSonRequest = Convert.ToString(content);

            var ticketContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TicketContainer>(resultJSonRequest);

            var tickets = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            foreach (var ticket in ticketContainer.tickets)
            {
                var ticketAsJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticket);
                var flatTicket = JsonHelper.DeserializeAndFlatten(ticketAsJsonString);
                tickets.Add(flatTicket);
            }
            var headers = tickets
                .Select(x => x.Keys.Cast<string>())

                .Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), (aggregate, entry) => aggregate.Union(entry))
                .Where(x => new string[] { "id", "subject"}.Contains(x.ToLower()))
                .ToList();

            table = new DataTable();

            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(header);
            }

            foreach (var ticket in tickets)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (var entry in ticket)
                {
                    if (headers.Contains(entry.Key, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        row[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
                    }
                }

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            if (counter == 1)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
                }

                csv.NextRecord();
            }
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                for (var p = 0; p < table.Columns.Count; p++)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(row[p]);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }

        }
        await getTickets();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AddLog(e.Message);
    }
}  


public static async Task getUsers()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/testapi/testUsers.json");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var content = response.Content;

        string resultJSonRequest = Convert.ToString(content);

        var ticketContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TicketContainer>(resultJSonRequest);

        var tickets = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        foreach (var ticket in ticketContainer.organizations)
        {
            var ticketAsJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticket);
            var flatTicket = JsonHelper.DeserializeAndFlatten(ticketAsJsonString);
            tickets.Add(flatTicket);
        }

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        var headers = tickets
                .Select(x => x.Keys.Cast<string>())

                .Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), (aggregate, entry) => aggregate.Union(entry))
                .Where(x => new string[] { "id", "name" }.Contains(x.ToLower()))
                .ToList();

        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(header);
        }

        foreach (var ticket in tickets)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            foreach (var entry in ticket)
            {
                if (headers.Contains(entry.Key, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    row[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
                }
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        using (var textWriter = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"users.csv")))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter))
            {
                csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName);
                }

                csv.NextRecord();

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        csv.WriteField(row[i]);
                    }
                    csv.NextRecord();
                }
            }
        }
     await getUsers();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AddLog(e.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Si colocas el codigo que hasta el momento llevas la comunidad podra darte una respuesta.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta agregando el codigo, gracias

Comment: Porque vuelves a llamar la misma funcion dentro de ella misma, en que momento se dejan de llamar recursivamente.

Comment: eso es lo que estoy tratando de entender para poder hacer modificaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi propuesta, crea un método que es el que va a llamar a los demás.

Método main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        RunMethods().Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AddLog(string.Format(ex.ToString()));
    }
}

private async Task RunMethods()
{
    await getTickets();
    await getUsers();
    //resto de métodos...
}
```

Los métodos asíncronos, mientras uses await para llamarlos, van a esperar hasta terminar, no se van a ejecutar al mismo tiempo todos, salvo quizás si olvidas poner el await.

Por cierto, supongo que estás mas familiarizado con java, lo digo por como nombras a tus métodos. En c# (y en .net en general) se usa la notación CamelCase para casi todo, a excepción de campos (fields) o parámetros, en vez de getTickets() quedaría mejor GetTickets();

Comment: intente usar lo que me mencionas pero me aparece un error en el main (an object reference is required to access non-static member method or property)

Comment: Cambia "private async Task RunMethods()" por "private static async Task RunMethods()".

Comment: Muchas gracias, me resulto bien. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Si usas `async/await` no quiere decir que realices paralelisto en la ejecucion de funciones, solo las ejecutas sin bloquear el hilo principal.

No definas todo como `static`, no esta bien. Defines una `class` que puedas instanciar para la funcionalidad he instancia desde el `Main`, algo como esto

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        UserService userService = new UserService();

        await userService.getTickets();
        await userService.getUsers();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AddLog(string.Format(ex.ToString()));
    }
}

public class UserService
{

    public async Task getTickets()
    {
        //codigo
    }

    public async Task getUsers()
    {
       //codigo
    }

}
```

[Async/await in a console application](https://recaffeinate.co/post/how-to-await-console-application/)

El uso del `await` en Main aplica si usas `c# 7.1`, sino vas a tener que usar algo como ser

```
Task.Run(async () => { 
        UserService userService = new UserService();

        await userService.getTickets();
        await userService.getUsers();
   }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: estoy tratando lo que me recomiendas pero al modificar el main ma aparece el siguiente error (Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point)

Comment: seguramente porque no tienes C# 7, podrias ver de usar la Task.Run()

Comment: si me resulta lo que me mencionas pero igual veo que los archivos se crean inmediatamente en vez de esperar que se cree uno a la vez

Comment: ya veo cual es el problema, de alguna forma la funcion numero 2 empieza antes que la numero 1 termine completamente. Hay alguna forma de poner un timing para manejar eso? al final de cada funcion?

Comment: creo que equivocas conceptos, no estas lanzando ejecuciones en paralelo, el async/await no bloquean el hilo, peor no paralelizan, cuando pones un await se quedara alli hasta que retorne la respuesta, no necesitas ningun timer

Comment: entiendo, y eso es lo que ocurre. como las funciones devuelven una respuesta, veo que la funcion proxima empieza a ejecutarse. el problema es que la funcion anterior va a devolver una respuesta varias veces lo cual es que escribe un archivo csv y hace un append en el para agregar todos los datos. hasta cuando ya termina su ejecucion. Eso necesito hacer que la proxima funcion solo se empieze a ejecutar una vez que la anterior termino por completo